# Does temporary lodging qualify as a moving expense for California tax deduction?

Tags: income-tax, tax-deduction, california, moving, eligible-expenses

Does anyone have a detailed source for what qualifies as a moving expense for California state tax purposes?

I moved to California from outside the US and when I arrived I stayed in temporary lodging (similar to airbnb) for 2 months before moving into a permanent residence. My company reimbursed me for this moving expense but the reimbursement was paid as regular taxable income and I would like to find out if I can get the tax I paid back with my CA tax return.

I cannot tell from the [CA Form 3913 instructions](https://www.ftb.ca.gov/forms/2022/2022-3913-instructions.html#D-Which-Moving-Expenses-Are-Deductible-and-Which-Are-Not) whether temporary accomodation at the destination is a qualifying expense.

These two excerpts seem relevant (emphasis mine)

> Travel. You can deduct the expenses of traveling (**including lodging within certain limitations**, but not meals) from your old home to your new home, including car expenses and air fare.

and

> Services or reimbursements provided by government. Do not include in income the value of moving and storage services provided by the government because of a permanent change of station. Similarly, do not include in income amounts received as a dislocation allowance, **temporary lodging expense, temporary lodging allowance, or move-in housing allowance.**

Answer (score 1):

I remember when this was something that was also handled on the Federal forms, but that is no longer the case.

I am also pulling the quotes from the same document: [2022 Instructions for Form FTB 3913 Moving Expense Deduction](https://www.ftb.ca.gov/forms/2022/2022-3913-instructions.html#D-Which-Moving-Expenses-Are-Deductible-and-Which-Are-Not)

> **Travel**. You can deduct the expenses of traveling (including lodging
> within certain limitations, but not meals) from your old home to your
> new home, including car expenses and air fare.

Looking at the specific line for Travel expenses:

> Line 2
>
> Enter the amount you paid to travel from your old home to your new
> home. This includes transportation and lodging on the way. Include
> costs for the day you arrive. The members of your household do not
> have to travel together or at the same time. But you can only include
> expenses for one trip per person. Do not include any house hunting
> expenses.

That means that once you arrive in the destination city the expenses you can claim for travel stop very quickly.

> I moved to California from outside the US and when I arrived I stayed
> in temporary lodging (similar to airbnb) for 2 months before moving
> into a permanent residence. My company reimbursed me for this moving
> expense but the reimbursement was paid as regular taxable income and I
> would like to find out if I can get the tax I paid back with my CA tax
> return.

That two months in the airbnb is not covered, because at that point you were living in the new city.

Your second quote:

> Services or reimbursements provided by government. Do not include in
> income the value of moving and storage services provided by the
> government because of a permanent change of station. Similarly, do not
> include in income amounts received as a dislocation allowance,
> temporary lodging expense, temporary lodging allowance, or move-in
> housing allowance

It is from a section related to a military permanent change of station, so unless you that was a military PCS that quote doesn't apply to you. If it was a military PCS, then talk to somebody on your base for assistance.